# Population Variance in r

Tags: r, variance

How can I calculate the population variance of my data using R?

I read there is a package called popvar but I have the Version 0.99.892 and I don't find the package

Comment: What software do you have Version 0.99.892 of? The current R version is 3.3.0. Maybe RStudio?  Don't confuse R and RStudio - RStudio is just a tool for writing R code.

Comment: R's `var` function divides by n-1 by default.  Multiplying the output of var by (n-1)/n will give you what want.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `var()` function in base R calculate the sample variance, and the population variance differs with the sample variance by a factor of `n / n - 1`. So an alternative to calculate population variance will be `var(myVector) * (n - 1) / n` where n is the length of the vector, here is an example:

```
x <- 1:10
var(x) * 9 /10
[1] 8.25
```

From the definition of population variance:

```
sum((x - mean(x))^2) / 10
[1] 8.25
```

Answer (score 9):

You already have a great answer, but I'd like to show that you can easily make your own convenience functions. It is surprising that a population variance/standard deviation function is not available in base `R`. It is available in `Excel`/`Calc` and other software. It wouldn't be difficult to have such a function. It could be named `sdp` or `sd.p` or be invoked with `sd(x, pop = TRUE)`

Here is a basic version of population variance with no type-checking:

```
  x <- 1:10
  varp <- function(x) mean((x-mean(x))^2)
  varp(x)
  ## [1] 8.25
```

To scale up, if speed is an issue, colSums and/or colMeans may be used (see: https://rdrr.io/r/base/colSums.html)

Comment: Also surprising that there is no skewness (with/without adjustment) or kurtosis or raw moments in base ``R``...

Answer (score 2):

You can find the details on package `popvar` here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PopVar/index.html - You can install it using the command `install.packages("PopVar");`  Note that the name is case sensitive (capital P, capital V).

Comment: It will be helpful if you explain how to use it. I tried **PopVar(c(1,2,3))**  and got error: *Error: could not find function "PopVar"*.

Comment: @HabeebPerwad You must first load the package `PopVar` to use the function `PopVar::PopVar`

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER `PopVar::` has only two tab completions `PopVar::pop.predict` and `PopVar::x.val'. I couldn't find `PopVar::PopVar`.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the population variance with the following function:

```
pvar <- function(x) {
  sum((x - mean(x))**2) / length(x)
}
```

where `x` is a numeric vector that keeps the data of your population. For example:

```
> x <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 14)
> pvar(x)
[1] 20
```